# How to get n-th Sunday date of the month in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, calendar

How to get first sunday or nth sunday or monday (any day) date in Objective C coding.

For example :- I just want to show date of friendship day in my app every year.

But, friendship comes 1st Sunday of Aug. So, date will change every year. here I need to find what is the date of 1st Sunday in Aug every year.

is there any logic to find the date of nth Sunday.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a NSDateComponents object and set the appropriate values,
In You example you would do:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

dateComponents.year = 2011; // set the current year or whatever year you want here
dateComponents.month = 8;
dateComponents.weekday = 1; // sunday is 1, monday is 2, ...
dateComponents.weekdayOrdinal = 1; // this means, the first of whatever weekday you specified
```

To convert this into a NSDate-object, you just do:

```
//you may want to use another calendar object here
NSDate *myDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
[dateComponents release]; //don't forget memory management ;)
```

Comment: Small query.. I want to find 2nd Sunday from last week.. is there any way to find by changing weekdayOrdinal to -ve value `dateComponents.weekdayOrdinal = -2;`

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `NSDateComponents` in combination with `NSCalendar`'s `dateFromComponents:` method:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *c = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[c setYear:2012];
[c setWeekday:1]; // Sunday
[c setWeekdayOrdinal:3]; // The 3rd Sunday

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    [c setMonth:i];
    NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:c];
    NSLog(@"Date[%i]: %@",i,date);
}

[c release];
[gregorian release];
```

Comment: You code is very useful to get every month 3rd sunday. Can you please help, one more query How to get total number Sundays in a month?

Comment: There might be a better way, but you can use this `NSCalendar` method:

- (NSRange)rangeOfUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)smaller inUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)larger forDate:(NSDate *)date

to get the number of days in a month, then subtract the date of the first Sunday and divide by 7 (and `floor` the result). You'll need to check for off-by-one issues with this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. You can find more information in the [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470-SW1).

To find the first Sunday in August:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setWeekday:1]; // Sunday
[components setWeekdayOrdinal:1]; // The first Sunday in the month
[components setMonth:8]; // August
[components setYear:2011];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

Answer (score 0):

you check the first day of the month.

```
unsigned units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:units fromDate:date];
```

Get the day using [components day]; <-1 for Sunday.After this it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to review the `NSCalendar` class [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html)

Of specific interest will be the method `- (NSUInteger)ordinalityOfUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)smaller inUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)larger forDate:(NSDate *)date`